# Using a Subquery in a Recursive CTE

Tags: sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression, parent

I have an SQL table which contains item numbers and the assemblies into which they are built, such that there is a line for each item, and it's common for an item to have multiple lines for the multiple assemblies into which it would go.  Likewise, each assembly also has a line where they are paired with the assemblies into which THEY go, and this is continued until we reach a top assembly, which is NULL in the Assembly field.  The data in this table (ttibom010124) looks like this:

```
Assembly (t_mitm)    Item (t_sitm)
TOPASSY1             SUBASSY1
TOPASSY2             SUBASSY2
SUBASSY1             PART1
SUBASSY1             PART2
SUBASSY2             PART3
SUBASSY2             PART4
PART1                SUBPART1
PART2                SUBPART2
PART3                SUBPART3
PART4                SUBPART4
```

Each Item also has a set of contractual flowdown Characteristics, defined as comma-separated integers in a single string, which is located in a different table.  That table (tqmptc018124) would look like this:

```
Item (t_item)   Characteristics (t_cdf_qcod)
SUBPART4        01,02,03
SUBPART3        04,05,06
SUBPART2        07,08,09
SUBPART1        10,11,12
PART4           13,14,15
PART3           16,17,18
PART2           19,20,21
PART1           22,23,24
SUBASSY2        25,26,27
SUBASSY1        28,29,30
TOPASSY1        NULL
TOPASSY2        NULL
```

There is another table that houses descriptive information about each Item (ttcibd001124), in particular the overall Product Line in which the Item is used.  That table is actually huge, but the relevant columns are:

```
Item (t_item)   Product Line (t_cpln)    Item Code (t_citg)
SUBPART4        B21500                   RAW
SUBPART3        B21500                   RAW
SUBPART2        B21500                   RAW
SUBPART1        B21500                   RAW
PART1           B21500                   MFG
PART2           B21500                   MFG 
PART3           B21500                   MFG
PART4           B21500                   MFG
SUBASSY2        B21500                   MFG
SUBASSY1        B21500                   MFG
TOPASSY1        B21500                   FNG
TOPASSY2        B21500                   FNG
```

The last table (ttcmcs061101) is a small table which stores the relationship between the Product Line code and the human-readable Description.  Here are a few example lines:

```
Product Line (t_cpln)   Description (t_dsca)
B21500                  Fiber Optics
B36710                  Eurofighter
B65100                  CT Scan
```

I need to create a report where we would input one of those Characteristics integers, we search the strings in that table for the Items which contain that integer, and then display the relevant top assemblies alongside each item.  I'm testing in SSMS right now, so the inputs are currently hardcoded, but I will parameterize them when I move the code to Report Builder.

So far I have working blocks of code that do what I want individually.  I can hardcode in a single Item for which I can find the Top Assembly.  I also have a small block that will accept a Characteristic and output all the Items on which that Characteristic is applied.  However, when I try to use the Characteristic SELECT statement as a Subquery in the block that finds the Top Assembly, I get a huge list of Items and Assemblies that don't have the Characteristic I'm interested in even though that's part of the input.

```
-- This block is a recursive CTE that finds the top assemblies 
-- by moving from line to line through the Bill of Materials table.
WITH CTE_TopAssy (
    AssyItem
   ,SubItem)
AS (
    SELECT
        BOM.t_mitm
       ,BOM.t_sitm
    FROM ttibom010124 AS BOM
    WHERE BOM.t_sitm IN

        -- This is a subquery that is supposed to output all the Items 
        -- that contain the Characteristic number from the WHERE line.
        (
            SELECT
                ItemsQD.t_item AS SubqueryItem
            FROM tqmptc018124 AS ItemsQD
            WHERE ItemsQD.t_cdf_qcod LIKE '%03%'
        )  -- 03 is the Characteristic we're searching by

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            BOM.t_mitm
           ,BOM.t_sitm
        FROM ttibom010124 AS BOM
        INNER JOIN CTE_TopAssy
            ON BOM.t_sitm = CTE_TopAssy.AssyItem
)

-- This is the main query that produces the actual output.
-- It contains references to other tables from which other data tied to the Item number are pulled.
SELECT DISTINCT
        LTRIM(RTRIM(CTE_TopAssy.AssyItem)) AS [Top Assembly]
       ,ItemData.t_cpln                    AS [Product Line]
       ,PLDesc.t_dsca                      AS [PL Name]
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(CTE_TopAssy.SubItem))  AS Item
    FROM CTE_TopAssy
    INNER JOIN ttcibd001124 AS ItemData
        ON CTE_TopAssy.AssyItem = ItemData.t_item
    INNER JOIN ttcmcs061101 AS PLDesc
        ON ItemData.t_cpln = PLDesc.t_cpln
    --FNG is for Finished Goods, and is the characteristic by which we identify Top Assemblies
    WHERE ItemData.t_citg = 'FNG'  
    ORDER BY
        [Product Line]
       ,[Top Assembly]
;
```

The output is in the expected format, but instead of limiting the returned results to Top Assemblies for those items with the desired Characteristic, I'm getting all kinds of Items and Assemblies that are unrelated and don't have that Characteristic.  This is how the output appears:

```
Top Assembly     Product Line     PL Name               Item
TOPASSY2         B21500           Fiber Optics          SUBASSY2
```

Everything is in the right place and of the right type, but simply not being filtered by the Characteristic we selected.  In this example output where we searched for '%03%', We have the right Top Assembly, but the Item is incorrect - it should be SUBPART4.  In my production environment I'm getting Items that have the wrong Characteristics or ones that don't even have them assigned, and they're being followed to Top Assemblies that shouldn't be part of the output.

The expected result for a '%03%' search would be:

```
Top Assembly     Product Line     PL Name               Item
TOPASSY2         B21500           Fiber Optics          SUBPART4
```

The expected result for a '%20%' search would be:

```
Top Assembly     Product Line     PL Name               Item
TOPASSY1         B21500           Fiber Optics          PART2
```

There are no error messages.

I am sure that the problem has something to do with inputting an array of lines instead of a single value, but I have no idea what to do about it.

I have added an SQL Fiddle with this new test data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e77e5/5/0

Comment: I see 4 tables in your query: tqmptc018124, ttibom010124, ttcibd001124, ttcmcs061101, but only two tables in your question without name. Please provide example data and correct name for all the 4 tables.

Comment: @AdamYan I have added descriptions and examples of the other two tables as requested.  Please let me know if anything else would be helpful!

Comment: t_citg column is not in your example table.

Comment: @AdamYan Added!

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: You can follow [this guideline](https://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/) for how to help us help you.

Comment: @AdamYan I have updated the example data so it will run in an SQL Fiddle and added a link to the question body. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e77e5

Comment: I cannot open your link.

Comment: Can you update your query like in my answer below with expected result?

Comment: @AdamYan Added expected results and tried a new Fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

There is no data returned with your example data and query. 
Please update your question.

Here is my query:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ttibom010124') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ttibom010124

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tqmptc018124') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tqmptc018124

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ttcibd001124') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ttcibd001124

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ttcmcs061101') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ttcmcs061101

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CTE_TopAssy') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #CTE_TopAssy


SELECT '6525039002' AS t_mitm, '8D004C0N01' AS t_sitm INTO #ttibom010124 UNION
SELECT '731114300G' AS t_mitm, '7311143000' AS t_sitm UNION
SELECT '731114300G' AS t_mitm, '7311113000' AS t_sitm UNION
SELECT '731114300G' AS t_mitm, '7C09E00PG0' AS t_sitm UNION
SELECT NULL         AS t_mitm, '731114300G' AS t_sitm UNION
SELECT '731114300G' AS t_mitm, '9L35WMP032' AS t_sitm UNION
SELECT '731114400G' AS t_mitm, '7311144000' AS t_sitm UNION
SELECT '731114400G' AS t_mitm, '7311113000' AS t_sitm UNION
SELECT '6525039000' AS t_mitm, '8D004C0N01' AS t_sitm UNION
SELECT '6525039001' AS t_mitm, '8D004C0N01' AS t_sitm UNION
SELECT '6525039003' AS t_mitm, '8D004C0N01' AS t_sitm UNION
SELECT '6525039004' AS t_mitm, '8D004C0N01' AS t_sitm

SELECT '8D004C0N01' AS t_item, '1,4,10,12,19,21,34,44B,49B,59' AS t_cdf_qcod INTO #tqmptc018124 UNION
SELECT '7311144000' AS t_item, '1,4,10,12,19A,21,34,44A,49B,59' AS t_cdf_qcod UNION
SELECT '7C09E00PG0' AS t_item, '1,4,10B,12,19,21,34,44A,49B,59,61' AS t_cdf_qcod UNION
SELECT '7311113000' AS t_item, '1,4,12,32,41,54A' AS t_cdf_qcod 

SELECT '8D004C0N01' AS t_item, 'B21500' AS t_cpln, 'MFG' AS t_citg INTO #ttcibd001124 UNION
SELECT '7311144000' AS t_item, 'B21500' AS t_cpln, 'RAW' AS t_citg UNION
SELECT '7C09E00PG0' AS t_item, 'B36710' AS t_cpln, 'RAW' AS t_citg UNION
SELECT '7311113000' AS t_item, 'B65100' AS t_cpln, 'FNG' AS t_citg 

SELECT 'B21500' AS t_cpln, 'Fiber Optics' AS t_dsca INTO #ttcmcs061101 UNION
SELECT 'B36710' AS t_cpln, 'Eurofighter' AS t_dsca UNION
SELECT 'B65100' AS t_cpln, 'CT Scan' AS t_dsca


;
-- This block is a recursive CTE that finds the top assemblies 
-- by moving from line to line through the Bill of Materials table.
WITH CTE_TopAssy (
    AssyItem
   ,SubItem)
AS (
    SELECT
        BOM.t_mitm
       ,BOM.t_sitm
    FROM #ttibom010124 AS BOM
    WHERE BOM.t_sitm IN

        -- This is a subquery that is supposed to output all the ICNs 
        -- that contain the SQAP number from the WHERE line.
        (
            SELECT
                ItemsQD.t_item AS SubqueryItem
            FROM #tqmptc018124 AS ItemsQD
            WHERE ItemsQD.t_cdf_qcod LIKE '%49B%'
        )  -- 49B is the Characteristic we're searching by

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            BOM.t_mitm
           ,BOM.t_sitm
        FROM #ttibom010124 AS BOM
        INNER JOIN CTE_TopAssy
            ON BOM.t_sitm = CTE_TopAssy.AssyItem
)
SELECT
        *
    INTO #CTE_TopAssy
    FROM CTE_TopAssy
--AssyItem      SubItem
--6525039000    8D004C0N01
--6525039001    8D004C0N01
--6525039002    8D004C0N01
--6525039003    8D004C0N01
--6525039004    8D004C0N01
--731114300G    7C09E00PG0
--731114400G    7311144000
--NULL          731114300G


-- This is the main query that produces the actual output.
-- It contains references to other tables from which other data tied to the Item number are pulled.
SELECT DISTINCT
        LTRIM(RTRIM(#CTE_TopAssy.AssyItem)) AS [Top Assembly]
       ,ItemData.t_cpln                     AS [Product Line]
       ,PLDesc.t_dsca                       AS [PL Name]
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(#CTE_TopAssy.SubItem))  AS Item
    FROM #CTE_TopAssy
    INNER JOIN #ttcibd001124 AS ItemData
        ON #CTE_TopAssy.AssyItem = ItemData.t_item
    INNER JOIN #ttcmcs061101 AS PLDesc
        ON ItemData.t_cpln = PLDesc.t_cpln
    --FNG is for Finished Goods, and is the characteristic by which we identify Top Assemblies
    --WHERE ItemData.t_citg = 'FNG'
    ORDER BY
        [Product Line]
       ,[Top Assembly]
;
```

**  Edit Begin  **

If I understand well, you want to keep the original subitem with its top assembly. 
I would recommand to create a scalor valued function for this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Get_Top_Assembly (
    @P_SubItem VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result_AssyItem VARCHAR(255);
    WITH CTE_TopAssy 
    AS (
        SELECT
            BOM.t_mitm AS AssyItem
           ,BOM.t_sitm AS SubItem
        FROM ttibom010124 AS BOM
        WHERE BOM.t_sitm  = @P_SubItem
            UNION ALL

            SELECT
                BOM.t_mitm
               ,BOM.t_sitm
            FROM ttibom010124 AS BOM
            INNER JOIN CTE_TopAssy
                ON BOM.t_sitm = CTE_TopAssy.AssyItem
    )

    SELECT @Result_AssyItem = CTE_TopAssy.AssyItem
    FROM CTE_TopAssy
    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result_AssyItem

END

GO;

WITH CTE_TopAssy
AS (
    SELECT
        dbo.Get_Top_Assembly(ItemsQD.t_item) AS AssyItem
       ,ItemsQD.t_item                       AS SubItem
    FROM tqmptc018124 AS ItemsQD
    WHERE ItemsQD.t_cdf_qcod LIKE '%03%'
        OR ItemsQD.t_cdf_qcod LIKE '%20%'
)

-- This is the main query that produces the actual output.
-- It contains references to other tables from which other data tied to the Item number are pulled.
SELECT DISTINCT
        LTRIM(RTRIM(CTE_TopAssy.AssyItem)) AS [Top Assembly]
       ,ItemData.t_cpln                    AS [Product Line]
       ,PLDesc.t_dsca                      AS [PL Name]
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(CTE_TopAssy.SubItem))  AS Item
    FROM CTE_TopAssy
    INNER JOIN ttcibd001124 AS ItemData
        ON CTE_TopAssy.AssyItem = ItemData.t_item
    INNER JOIN ttcmcs061101 AS PLDesc
        ON ItemData.t_cpln = PLDesc.t_cpln
    --FNG is for Finished Goods, and is the characteristic by which we identify Top Assemblies
    WHERE ItemData.t_citg = 'FNG'  
    ORDER BY
        [Product Line]
       ,[Top Assembly]
```

Results:

```
Top Assembly    Product Line    PL Name         Item
TOPASSY1        B21500          Fiber Optics    PART2
TOPASSY2        B21500          Fiber Optics    SUBPART4
```

** 2nd Edit END BEGIN **

Here is CTE version, not fully optimized for performence but it should be easy to understand.

```
WITH CTE_Items
AS (
    SELECT
        ItemsQD.t_item AS SubItem
    FROM tqmptc018124 AS ItemsQD
    WHERE ItemsQD.t_cdf_qcod LIKE '%03%'
        OR ItemsQD.t_cdf_qcod LIKE '%20%'
),

CTE_Assy_Hier
AS (
    SELECT
        BOM.t_mitm AS AssyItem
       ,BOM.t_sitm AS SubItem
       ,i.SubItem  AS Original_SubItem
       ,1          AS Lvl
    FROM ttibom010124 AS BOM
    INNER JOIN CTE_Items i
        ON BOM.t_sitm = i.SubItem
        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            BOM.t_mitm
           ,BOM.t_sitm
           ,CTE_Assy_Hier.Original_SubItem
           ,1 + Lvl AS Lvl
        FROM ttibom010124 AS BOM
        INNER JOIN CTE_Assy_Hier
            ON BOM.t_sitm = CTE_Assy_Hier.AssyItem
),

CTE_MAX_LVL
AS (
    SELECT
        MAX(Lvl) AS maxLvl
       ,Original_SubItem
    FROM CTE_Assy_Hier
    GROUP BY
        Original_SubItem
),
CTE_TopAssy
AS (
    SELECT
        t.AssyItem
       ,t.Original_SubItem AS SubItem
    FROM CTE_Assy_Hier t
    INNER JOIN CTE_MAX_LVL m
        ON t.Original_SubItem = m.Original_SubItem
        AND t.Lvl = m.maxLvl
)
-- This is the main query that produces the actual output.
-- It contains references to other tables from which other data tied to the Item number are pulled.
SELECT DISTINCT
        LTRIM(RTRIM(CTE_TopAssy.AssyItem)) AS [Top Assembly]
       ,ItemData.t_cpln                    AS [Product Line]
       ,PLDesc.t_dsca                      AS [PL Name]
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(CTE_TopAssy.SubItem))  AS Item
    FROM CTE_TopAssy
    INNER JOIN ttcibd001124 AS ItemData
        ON CTE_TopAssy.AssyItem = ItemData.t_item
    INNER JOIN ttcmcs061101 AS PLDesc
        ON ItemData.t_cpln = PLDesc.t_cpln
    --FNG is for Finished Goods, and is the characteristic by which we identify Top Assemblies
    WHERE ItemData.t_citg = 'FNG'
    ORDER BY
        [Product Line]
       ,[Top Assembly]
;
```

**  Edit END  **

Comment: I pasted your code into SSMS, and it doesn't throw any flags before execution on our production data.  However, I get two error messages on execution:

````Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Get_Top_Assembly, Line 31 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Get_Top_Assembly, Line 58 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near 'Top Assembly'.
````

Comment: Ah, did a bit more digging.  Apparently permission to use CREATE FUNCTION is denied on the database I'm working on.

Comment: It is not hard to expand the function to subquery or one more CTE.

Comment: I finally got a chance to come back to this, and I was able to adapt your second edit for use in the live environment.  Thank you so much for your patience and help!